# Помогите удалить html форматирование и сократить кол-во символов

Tags: php

Вывожу description так
    `<?php echo $response->results[0]->description;?>` - выводит весь текст с форматированием.

Пытаюсь сократить текст до 160 символов, так `<?php echo substr($response->results[0]->description,0,160); ?>` - результат странный, значение постоянно изменяется, то меньше 160 символов, то больше и html форматирование остается.

Как удалить весь html и сократить символы до 160 - верно?
Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А каких символов ? английских или русских ? Если русских, попробуйте использовать `mb_substr()`

Comment: И английских и русских, действительно, обратил внимание, что английские сокращает точнее. Сейчас попробую ваш вариант.

Comment: И я не увижу у вас кода, который бы убирал теги, каким нибудь strip_tags, например

Comment: Здорово! mb_substr() работает и с русскими и с английскими символами. Спасибо! Вот с html пока не понял...

Comment: Сейчас у меня та `<?php echo mb_substr($response->results[0]->description,0,160); ?>` strip_tags после echo дает ошибку. Еще прочел, что strip_tags не проверяет корректность HTML кода, незавершенные тэги могу привести к удалению текста, не входящего в тэги. Пока не вник.

Comment: Удаляйте тэги до обрезки

Comment: Я не знаю как это сделать